# Extract coordinate values in xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I would like to extract the values of the coordinate variables.

For example I create a DataArray as:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
years_arr=range(1982,1986)
time = pd.date_range('14/1/' + str(years_arr[0]) + ' 12:00:00', periods=len(years_arr), freq=pd.DateOffset(years=1))
lon = range(20,24)
lat = range(10,14)
arr1 = xr.DataArray(data, coords=[time, lat, lon], dims=['time', 'latitude', 'longitude'])
```

I now would like to output the `lon` values from `arr1`.
I'm asking as `arr1` going into a function so I may not have the `lon` values available.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`arr1.coords['lon']` gives you longitude as a `xarray.DataArray`, and `arr1.coords['lon'].values` gives you the values as a numpy array.

Answer (score 6):

Another possible solution is:

```
time, lat, lon = arr1.indexes.values()
```

The result is a Float64Index for your lat/lon coordinates.